# Storyboard Suddenly GONE from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

While I was working on this Xcode project, compile and run an app, the two files suddenly gone!!!

It was working fine and I run the app a few times already. Anybody has any clue why is it happening?

My Mac is warning for Disk Space recently. Would it be something related?

Please help...I have been working on the project for a few weeks already. Anyway I could recover what I lost? I archive it a few hours ago into an IPA, can I recover the lost files from there?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

[image]

EDIT-------------------------------------

The Files are gone and I have to work for 12 hours to get my app back to running as it was before.

I think the problem was that my Mac was out of Disk Space, and when I tried to run, the AutoSave from Xcode failed to save. And for some reason the failure caused Xcode the delete the file when saving failed.

Learning from the lesson. I will do what folks here suggested from now on:
1) Time Machine
2) Git 
3) Periodic zip the project and put on Dropbox and an external hard disk
4) Always ensure there's enough disk space

Thanks all. Hope nobody else would have to go through what I went through.

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you using "Time Machine"?  If not, consider this a wake-up call.

2) Use Spotlight (the magnifying glass in the upper right corner of your Macintosh menu) to find those missing files.

3)  Once you do find them, delete the old files and re-add them to your project, making sure the "Target Membership" checkboxes are set.

Comment: Really disappear from my Mac! Could find the lost files at all anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Disk space warning is a good indication that things of this sort could happen. Some say you need to have %50 of the disk free. Whether it's true or not, filling the disk to the point system warning is a serious sign that you should free up enough space.

Sometimes a restart can magically 'find' a file, but I'm sure you tried that already. I'd try to find it in the project folder, or on the disk itself and not through XCode.

Most chances are the files are there, but XCode cannot see them for some reason.

Comment: Tried to search everywhere, couldn't find the files. Nah... So stupid I didn't bother to handle the disk space warning...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in the projects directory?

Also are you using source control (Locally or git) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, some of my views on the storyboard disappeared after Xcode crashed. After looking for a while for an answer I noticed the view still shows on the hierarchy panel. checking its properties I noticed that Xcode had changed my width and height properties to 0. Once I restored them, the view shows again. Long story short, check the properties, if the width and height are 0 the view becomes invisible.